# Creating a portable encrypted credential store

Tags: security, authentication, powershell

There have been a few questions over on SO recently about securely storing credentials in Powershell scripts. Because `ConvertFrom-SecureString` uses DPAPI it makes the output only valid for that user, which makes creating credentials for service accounts etc. occasionally awkward.

I have had this script lying around for a while, that creates a private key for `ConvertFrom-SecureString` stores that and the password in a custom object, and then encrypts the whole thing with a self signed certificate.

While it all works perfectly well, I've always been a little nervous about how it creates the certificate. While I (think I) understand what the parameters to `New-SelfSignedCertificate` are doing I'm still not convinced it is configured in the most appropriate / secure way (obviously after this, the certificate is exported / deleted / secured / imported where needed).

For starters, I know backticking is generally frowned upon, but I prefer it because it aids readability.

This is the main function I'm concerned with. Would a different provider be 'better', should I be using elliptic curve, is the concept solid. etc.

```
#Requires –Version 5

function New-Certificate
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $CertificateSubject
    )

    New-SelfSignedCertificate -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1") `
                            -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" `
                            -DnsName $CertificateSubject `
                            -CertStoreLocation  "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" `
                            -KeyExportPolicy ExportableEncrypted `
                            -KeyUsage DataEncipherment `
                            -KeyUsageProperty All `
                            -KeyLength 2048 
}
# New-Certificate -CertificateSubject "My Test Certificate"
```

From there there are three functions, that I'd be curious of your thoughts on.

For a simple export function, I considered putting a path checker there. If it fails, then it is being used interactively, so it's just easier to fix as it's called.

```
function Export-PublicCredentials
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $CertificateSubject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $filePath
    )

    $Certificate = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ `
                    -DocumentEncryptionCert | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $CertificateSubject} )

    Export-Certificate -Cert $Certificate -FilePath $filePath 
}
```

Then the real part, create a key, store the credential, wrap it all up in a cert:

```
function Encrypt-Credentials
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $CertificateSubject
    )
    $Credential = Get-Credential 

    $key = New-Object byte[](32)
    $rng = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
    $rng.GetBytes($key)

    $SecureStringWithKey = $Credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $key 

    $thumbprint = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ `
                    -DocumentEncryptionCert | 
                     Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $CertificateSubject} ).Thumbprint

    $object = (New-Object pscustomobject | 
        Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty -Name "Key" -Value $key | 
        Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty -Name "Username" -Value $Credential.UserName |  
        Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty -Name "SecureStringWithKey" -Value $SecureStringWithKey 
    )
    $json = $object | ConvertTo-Json

    $EncryptedKey = Protect-CmsMessage -Content $json -To $thumbprint

    Write-Output $EncryptedKey 
}

$EncrypteString = Encrypt-Credentials -CertificateSubject "My Test Certificate"
```

Finally, what would be the most called parameter, the decryption. The idea here is that the encrypted string is put somewhere accessible (A HTTP share, or a local disk etc) the encrypted string is decrypted and deserialised and then you get a credential object, as well as the key to pass back to `ConvertTo-SecureString` to get the PSCredential object back.

```
function Decrypt-Credentials
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $EncryptedCredentials
    )

    $AuthObject = (Unprotect-CmsMessage -Content $EncryptedCredentials | ConvertFrom-Json)

    $secureStringPassword = $AuthObject.SecureStringWithKey | 
                    ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $AuthObject.Key.value

    $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
             -argumentlist $AuthObject.Username, $secureStringPassword

    Write-Output $cred 

}

#Decrypt-Credentials -EncryptedCredentials $EncrypteString
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know enough about handling credentials to know whether the overall concept is sound, so I will ignore that aspect.  I do have the following suggestions regarding the details of your code.

#### Use Splats Instead of Backticks

```
$splat = @{
    TextExtension = @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1")
    Provider      = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
    DnsName       = $CertificateSubject
    CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
    KeyExportPolicy   = 'ExportableEncrypted'
    KeyUsage          = 'DataEncipherment'
    KeyUsageProperty  = 'All'
    KeyLength         = 2048 
}
New-SelfSignedCertificate @splat
```

This has the following advantages over backticked named parameters:

- **can be converted to a parameters object and piped to the command with minimal alterations**
- **`$splat` key/value pairs can be conditionally added and removed**
- less typing to achieve both nice layout and correctness
- satisfies the "no-backticks" pedants

#### Try to Start New Lines on `|`

```
$Certificate = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ -DocumentEncryptionCert | 
    Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $CertificateSubject}
```

This might look a bit quirky for just two commands in the pipeline, but it expands to many commands well:

```
$folderNames = Get-ChildItem |
    ? { $_.Name -like '*c*' } |
    Sort { $_.LastWriteTime } |
    Select -First 2 |
    Sort { $_.CreationTime } -Descending |
    % Name
```

#### Separate Parameters with Whitespace

Parameters should be separated with whitespace:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $CertificateSubject,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $FilePath
)
```

This doesn't make a big difference when you only have four lines in your `Param()` block.  However, [when your parameter and attribute count grows](https://github.com/alx9r/ToolFoundations/blob/1b2bd4507012e796ba3f8b040091199345fe56c8/Functions/filePath.ps1#L889-L945), the whitespace makes it much easier to see where one parameter ends and the next begins.

#### Adopt a Capitalization Convention

I don't recognize the capitalization convention you are using. For example, you have two parameters called `CertificateSubject` and `filePath`.  PowerShell parameters we see in Microsoft-provided cmdlets seem to be [CamelCaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).  I would stick to that.

For my code, I use mixedCase for local variables.  This way I can immediately tell when I am working with a parameter.  That is important because modifying child objects of a parameter can have consequences outside of the scope.

Different projects seem to have different conventions.  The important thing is that you pick one and stick to it.

#### Create `PSObjects` with `@{}`

Create `PSObjects` using a hashtable like this:

```
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Key                 = $key
    Username            = $Credential.UserName
    SecureStringWithKey = $SecureStringWithKey 
}
```

This has much less cruft and might be faster than `Add-Member`.

#### Validate your Parameters

You should consider validating the parameters when they are passed to your functions:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({$_ | Test-ValidCertificateSubject})]
    [string]
    $CertificateSubject,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({$_ | Test-ValidFilePath})]
    [string]
    $FilePath
)
```

That will catch problematic parameters early.  `[string]` ensures that the parameter is a string (or is coerced to one).  `ValidateScript()` allows you to use custom validation functions.  You'd have to write `Test-ValidCertificateSubject` yourself.  `Test-ValidFilePath` [already exists](https://github.com/alx9r/ToolFoundations/blob/1b2bd4507012e796ba3f8b040091199345fe56c8/Functions/filePath.ps1#L638).

#### This will Fail in Some Conditions

```
$Certificate = (Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ `
                -DocumentEncryptionCert | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $CertificateSubject} )

Export-Certificate -Cert $Certificate -FilePath $filePath
```

`$Certificate` could contain an array of certificates.  The call to `Export-Certificate` will fail if that is the case.  How best to fix this is a design decision that requires some judgment.  I find that arriving at a good solution is best achieved by setting up unit tests that include the problem case and trying a few different behaviors until you find the one that works best for your situation.  I doubt, though, that the best behavior is the current form which produces this cryptic error (pun intended):

```
Export-Certificate : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type  'Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.Certificate' required by parameter 'Cert'. 
Specified method is not supported.
```

Comment: I actually tried converting some of my script to use splatting, and quickly remembered why I prefer not using it. Mostly for the autocomplete, maybe one day they'll make splatting work with autocomplete. The only times I do use it is explicitly for the scenarios that you suggest. i.e. conditionally adding/removing and piping etc. The piping is definitely an improvement though

Comment: Are you unit testing? To validate your code's use of PowerShell's rather complicated parameter binding you need to _run_ the code with all applicable permutations of parameter values by unit testing. That will rigorously catch both invalid parameter names (which is the only thing autocomplete helps with) and also the hundreds of other nuanced and surprising quirks in the parameter binding system. [This post by Scott Nimrod](https://bizmonger.Wordpress.com/2015/07/29/are-you-a-professional-debuggerer/) explains why I unit test all my PowerShell code: More reliable code in less time.

Comment: That's a really good article, thanks for sharing, I'd definitely come under the debugger brand, though I'm not sure I'd be professional! - the main thing autocomplete helps me with is the 'oh yeah, I need that parameter too' memory optimisation

Comment: I added a few more suggestions to my answer.

Comment: FWIW, I use `help Function-WhoseParametersINeed` in the REPL to show the help while I'm composing the parameters at the call site.  Help provides a lot more relevant parameter information than does autocomplete.

Comment: Some great suggestions there, that will definitely be used when I come to writing it properly. - Your ToolFoundations scripts look really interesting too! (not to mention beautifully written!) - and it seems you've pushed me over the edge on the 'I really need to learn Powershell Unit testing' thought too.

Comment: Q: How do you know you when you need to unit test something written in PowerShell? A: When you've written something in PowerShell.